# Publishing Hosted Feature Layers to ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online

If you publish hosted feature layers, is there an option to make them private afterwards?

Reason being I have a layer I want to use using ArcGIS Online but it says the file is too large and the other option is to publish it. If there are any other workarounds I'd be happy to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can switch a layer from Public to Private at anytime. You can also create feature layer views from the hosted layer and have certain fields or filters applied to the views. These feature layer views can be public or private and not dependent on the parent hosted feature layer. They can also be styled and have the popup authored differently than the parent hosted feature layer. Also if your parent feature layer has editing enabled and is private the views can be non-editable and will not expose any of the editing capabilities you have on the private parent hosted feature layer.